# Setting each of the alphabet to a number

Tags: java

so I am trying to set each of the letter in the alphabet to a number like a = 1
b = 2 c =3 and so on.

```
int char = "a";
int[] num = new int{26};
for (int i = 0; i <num.length; i++){
System.out.print(i);
```

But after this i got Stuck so if you possible help me out. So when the users input a word like cat it would out put 3-1-20.

Comment: Why don't you just convert the text to ASCII and subtract 64 (uppercase) or 96 (lowercase)?

Comment: Check http://www.asciitable.com it shows you the mapping of letters to numbers, @Arc676 has great solution for you.

Comment: You don't even need to explicitly subtract 96. You can just do `character - 'a'`

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract `'a'` from each char and add `1`. E.g.

```
String input = "cat";
for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.print(c - 'a' + 1);
}
```

The code you posted doesn't compile as you can't assign a `String` to an `int` and `char` is a reserved word (name of a primitive type)

```
int char = "a";
```

You also mention that you want the output formatted like this `"3-1-20"`. This is one way to achieve that :

```
String input = "cat";
String[] out = new String[input.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
    out[i] = Integer.toString(input.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1);
}
System.out.println(String.join("-", out));
```

Both versions work only for lowercase English letters (`a` to `z`)

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a number to a character is called an "[encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)". As computers can only handle numbers internally, this happens all the time. Even this text here is encoded (probably into an encoding called "UTF-8") and then the resulting number is stored somewhere.

One very basic encoding is the so called [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (American Standard Code for Information Interchange). ASCII already does what you want, it assigns a number to each character, only that the number for "A" is 65 instead 1.

So, how does that help? We can assume that for the character A-z, the numeric value of a `char` is equal to the ASCII code (it's not true for every character, but for the most basic ones, it's good enough).

And this is why everyone here tells you to subtract 'A' or 'a': Your character is a char, which is a character, but also the numeric value of that character, so you can subtract 'A' (again, a char) and add 1:

```
'B' - 'A' + 1 = 2
```

because...

```
66 (numeric value of 'B') - 65 (numeric value of 'A') + 1 = 2
```

Actually, char is not ASCII, but UTF-8, but there it starts to get slightly bit more complex, so ASCII will suffice for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

the best way of doing this is to convert the String to a byte[], like this:

```
char[] buffer = str.toCharArray();
```

Then each of the characters can be converted to their byte-value (which are constants for a certain encoding), like this:

```
byte[] b = new byte[buffer.length];
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i] = (byte) buffer[i];
}
```

Now look at the resulting values and subtract/add some value to get the desired results!

Comment: And why do you need a byte array for this? The char array is enough to get the "desired results" using "subtract/add".